# Android, How to access a common method through two different threads?

Tags: android, serialization, android-asynctask

In my application I have two threads (I'm using AsyncTask class). in `doInBackground()` method of each thread i'm calling my own `getNewsItems(Url url)` method, this method will connect to server and get response. after that in `onPostExecute()` method of each thread, i'll call `displayData()` method to show results on screen.

The problem is when i run, the application crashes. I think its because these two thread have access to common methods in same time because when i separate common methods then the app runs successfully. I have no idea is it because of don't use of serialization?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put a `synchronized` modifier to your method that is accessed by multiple threads.

e.g.

```
public synchronized void getNewsItems(Url url){
    //some logic here
}
```

so that, When one thread is executing a synchronized method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first thread is done with the object.

you can also read about it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

UPDATE:

you can have the `getNewsItems(Url url)` in a separate class like this:

```
public class NewsItems{
  getNewsItems(Url url){
    //some logic here
  }
}
```

and then instantiate it within your threads like this:

```
public void run(){
  NewsItems ni = new NewsItems();
  ni.getNewsItems(url);
}
```

this way, same method will be called but in different class instances...

Comment: Thanks dear stjom, I did this but the application crashed as well. I have no idea why it acts like this. I wrote two getNewsItems(Url url) and two displayData(). It works fine but i don't like this way because i repeated two same methodes :(

Comment: you can put those methods in a separate class and just instantiate them within threads. This way, the same method is called but in different instances.

Comment: hi Hesam, i updated the code. you may try it so your code will look cleaner. =)

Comment: Yes this method is correct. thanks for spending time to solve my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

When two threads have access to common method there is no problem. Make your common method in different class and then share different object to two different threads . Dont make the common method static synchrozied .